# Using dlopen() on an executable

Tags: unix, executable, dlopen

I need to call a function from another program.  If the other program were a library, I could simply use dlopen and dlsym to get a handle to the function.  Unfortunately, the other program is a Unix Executable, and building it as a library is not an option.  Trying dlopen() on the executable gives this error message:

`dlopen([...]/testprogram, 1): no suitable image found. Did find: 
[...]/testprogram: can't map`

This isn't surprising, as dlopen is meant for use with libraries, not executables.  Is there any way to get dlopen and dlsym to work with executables?  If not, is there an alternative way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't open executables as libraries. The entry point of an executable will attempt to re-initialize the C library, and take over the `brk` pointer. This will corrupt your malloc heap. Additionally, the executable is likely to be mapped at a fixed address with no relocations, and if this address overlaps with anything already loaded, it's not possible to map it for that reason as well.

You need to refactor the other program into a library, or add a RPC interface to the other program.

Note that this does not necessarily apply for PIE executables. However, unless the executable is specifically designed for being `dlopen()`ed, this is unsafe, as `main()` will not be run, and any initialization done in `main()` therefore will not occur.

Comment: As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617099/call-function-in-unrelated-executable-linux/6619977#6619977, this answer is wrong for PIE executables, which are really a special form of shared libraries (and even have ET_DYN e_type).

Answer (score 12):

On some ELF systems (notably Linux), you can `dlopen()` PIE executables. When using GCC, just compile the executable with `-fpie` or `-fPIE`, and link it with `-pie`, and export the appropriate symbols using `--dynamic-list` or `-rdynamic` (explained in more detail in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292473/how-to-call-function-in-executable-from-my-library/6298434#6298434).

Comment: A [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713517/how-to-self-dlopen-an-executable-binary/19716028#19716028).

Answer (score 2):

Tool here to do precisely that, handles ASLR/PIE and non-ASLR/PIE.  Compiles on x86, ARM and MIPS (32 bit only).  Edit the Makefile to set ARCH param.

http://rtfc.org.uk/cliapi.html

It's my tool but it seems to do what you want.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

I appreciate how late I am to this party, but hey.

Answer (score 1):

To add the ability to load executables via dlopen is registered as refused glibc RFE (Request For Enhancement). A detailed look at the RFE and a possible approach for some special cases may be found at

[http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11754][1]

Excluding PIEs there would be to many problems behind the scenes to implement such a functionality.