# How to debug the .so source?

Tags: c++, linux

I want to know how to debug the inner source of a so file.
I have a so file,and i use dlopen() to open it,then I use dlsym() to load the method.
Now,I use g++ tools with the flag -g to compile it.It works very well, however I can't step into the so source by using the gdb command 'next'.

Comment: That's because "next" steps over function calls. Use "step" to step into functions!

Comment: Also: Since you're targetting gdb, you might want to use `-ggdb`.

Comment: Bonus also: Modern GDB has a text ui, add '-tui' to your gdb command line, e.g. `$ gdb -tui myapp`. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html

Comment: the .so is also compiled with -g ?

Comment: BTW, you are `dlsym`-ing not methods but function names. And please check that `dlopen` and `dlsym` succeeded (use `dlerror` on failure, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19716028/841108) ...)

Comment: @tristan ,yes I did.I have known that.3Q.

Comment: @Kaz,3q for answering this in time.

Comment: @kfsone ,3q for telling me the para -tui.

Comment: @kidoher: please accept and/or upvote appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing two different ways of running gdb.  Here's a link explaining how to iterate over your source code.

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html

Answer (score 1):

If *all* the code is compiled with `-g` (and that includes the code of the `dlopen`-ed shared object `.so` file and all the code of the main `dlopen`-ing program), then you *can* [step](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) into a function of your plugin with `gdb` (or even add a breakpoint inside).

It may be useful to use quite *recent versions* of the [GCC compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. 4.8) and of the [GDB debugger](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) (i.e. 7.6). Both have improved significantly and recently on these aspects.