# How am I able to run a shared library as an executable from the terminal?

Tags: linux, musl

from the musl libc FAQ

> Q: Where is ldd?
>
> musl’s dynamic linker comes with ldd functionality built in. Just create a symlink from ld-musl-$ARCH.so to /bin/ldd. If the dynamic linker was started as “ldd”, it will detect that and print the appropriate DSO information.

Inspecting `ld-musl-$ARCH.so` I found that it's a symlink to the musl `/usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so`

and that is definitely a shared library

```
$ file /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so
/usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=068deca2fec0ea2c50ec1e11166d25b3bb057431, not stripped
```

And it actually works which is nuts lol. I can actually do this:

```
$ /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so ./a.out
```

And it will work. But how is it possible that I can invoke a shared library from the terminal?

Comment: Possible [cross-site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables)

Comment: Related [Why and how are some shared libraries runnable, as though they are executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think I understand.

So basically a shared library is in fact an executable. And because musl is a libc implementation it defines the `_start()` function which is the real entry-point of the program. The `_start()` function would then calls the main function.

The developers of musl made it so that if you invoke their `libc.so` as `ld` or `ldd` they would detect that and act accordingly.

They can detect that because `_start()` does take `argc` and `argv` (which would then be passed on to `main()`) so they can see if `argv[0]` is "ld" or "ldd".

And thanks to @that other guy and @David C. Rankin for linking [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables). The answer there says that you can even have a shared library that defines `main()`.

So I tried that myself.

Here's `_start.c`

```
void
_start()
{
    asm("mov $60,%rax; mov $0,%rdi; syscall");
}
```

I compiled that on an x86_64 ubuntu linux machine with gcc 7.4.0 like so:

```
$ gcc -shared -nostdlib _start.c -o libwow.so
```

And then I called it:

```
$ ./libwow.so
$
```

It didn't do anything of course, but it did run.

It's a crazy world we live in :D

### EDIT:

On a crazier note. One can load executables as dynamic libraries using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19716028/3659011) to learn more.

### Conclusion:

Shared libraries and Executables are pretty much the same thing (`ELF` binaries).

Except that shared libs have no fixed entry-point address while executables do.

Also shared libs are `PIE` while binaries are not by default.

And I guess there are a few other minor differences :p

There are executables (traitors :p) that live among us that were really shared libs all along and we didn't know like `gawk` and `ntfsck`.

Look at this [Question/Answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects/960212) for more information.