# Is it possible to dlopen an executable binary?

Tags: linker, dlopen

I know dlopen is used for loading a shared library compiled with "-shared" and possibly "-fPIC".
But since the executable and dynamic library share the same format, I'm wondering if it is possible to directly load an executable?

It is acceptable that we may need to re-construct a customized dlopen and dlsym, just want to know whether it is possible to do such things while being transparent to the binaries.

BTW, It is also acceptable that the loaded executable cannot be reused (since it is not compiled with -fPIC).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try it, but whatever the result should be, it will be platform-dependent. (Make sure the executable is compiled and linked with option `-fPIC`.)

Answer (score 0):

This [used to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618319/50617) to `dlopen` a PIE executable on Linux, but [not anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59074126/50617) -- GLIBC-2.30 prohibits this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible to execute a `.so` file:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867

Can you turn the question around to compile the executable (application) as a '.so' file? With `-shared` etc?